# Not able to pass a variable in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

In the controller below, if I return `$friendPosts` (which has the post ids), the ids are shown in the view without problems.
But when I try to return the `$sharedPosts` (which has the whole row), nothing shows up in the view.

#### Controller

```
public function getProfile($email)
{
    $myFriends    = Auth::user()->friends()->lists('id');                 
    $friendShares = Share::where('user_id',$myFriends)->get();
    $friendPosts  = $friendShares->lists('post_id');
    $sharedPosts  = Post::where('id', $friendPosts)->get();

    return view('profile.index')
        ->with ('friendShares', $sharedPosts);
}
```

#### View

```
@foreach ($friendShares as $friendShares)
  <p> {{$friendShares}}</p>
@endforeach
```

Comment: You've typo within your code `->with ('friendShares', $shardPosts);` should be `->with ('friendShares', $sharedPosts);`

Comment: I'm sorry, this was a typo in this post only because I typed it.  The issue still persists.

Comment: Try to `var_dump` the `$sharedPosts` in the controller. If it's empty then it's likely a db issue (wrong/empty table)

Comment: var_dump gives an empty array, but I don't know why.  The $friendPosts returns 3 post ids successfully which should be matched in the Post table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$myFriends    = Auth::user()->friends()->lists('id');                 
$friendShares = Share::where('user_id',$myFriends)->get();
$friendPosts  = $friendShares->lists('post_id');
$sharedPosts  = Post::where('id', $friendPosts)->get();
```

should be

```
$myFriends    = Auth::user()->friends()->lists('id');                 
$friendShares = Share::whereIn('user_id',$myFriends)->get();
$friendPosts  = $friendShares->lists('post_id');
$sharedPosts  = Post::whereIn('id', $friendPosts)->get();
```

You are working with more ids, not just one, so you have to use `whereIn()` which looks trough an array of values.

Next time it would be useful if you tell us what you actually wanted/tried to do with your code.

Comment: Sure I will ... Thanks alot.

Comment: One more little thing ... Does this way of coding look normal , or is there a more efficient way to do the above ?

Comment: Sure! I always prefer to use model relationships instead of queries... Have a look at https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many. You would end up with something like `auth()->user()->friends()->posts()` where `posts()` would possibly be a `User` model scope that uses a `hasManyTrough` since I suppose you need to pass trough `Share` (https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).